# AngularJS Typeahead display object

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get my application to have a typeahead control in one of my views.
Currently I have it set up exactly the same as this example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/5kGZkNPZ7rIFfb4Rvxej?p=preview

But to fit my needs, I have to get it to show the entire object in the dropdown.
My array looks a bit like this:

```
self.tests = [
    {
        "detail": "27/06/2015, 1 Lines, £478.40",
        "title": "HOM026MA01|ww06-1526",
        "type": "O",
        "value": "W0669090"
    },
    {
        "detail": "25/06/2015, 3 Lines, £1390.92",
        "title": "BER0050000|andrew02",
        "type": "O",
        "value": "W0667777"
    }
];
```

so I changed my html to this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="controller.selected" typeahead="stuff as stuff.value for stuff in controller.tests | filter:$viewValue" />
```

As you can see, this will show the **value** of the json object, but I would like it to show the other details too.
Does anyone know how you can do that?

Comment: `show the other details` means? which property you wanted to show,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use string concatenation here

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" 
  ng-model="controller.selected" 
  typeahead="stuff.value + ' ' + stuff.title + ' '+  stuff.detail for stuff in controller.tests | filter:$viewValue" />
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5kGZkNPZ7rIFfb4Rvxej?p=preview)